# How do you iterate through a list of objects?

Tags: struts2, iterator

I have a User class that has a String username in it. I have a list of users that I'm trying to display in a table using

```
                         <s:iterator value="users" id="list">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><s:property value="#list.username" /></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                         </s:iterator>
```

The rows are being displayed the right number of times, so it's iterating through my list properly. However, I don't know how to access the username property to display it. Obviously what I have above isn't correct... Any ideas?

Answer (score 19):

First, in Struts2 2.1.x the `id` attribute is deprecated, `var` should be used instead ([ref](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/iterator.html))

<s>I think the # is misused there.</s> Besides, "list" seems a bad name for what is to be assigned in each iteration... I think "user" is more appropiate.

IIRC, the syntax is

```
 <s:iterator value="users" var="user">
  ...  <s:property value="#user.username" />
 </s:iterator>
```

Further, you don't need to assign the current item in the iterator for such a simple case. THis should also work:

```
 <s:iterator value="users">
  ...  <s:property value="username" />
 </s:iterator>
```

Also you might want to try this:

```
  <s:iterator value="users">
      ...  <s:property />      <!-- this outputs the full object, may be useful for debugging -->
  </s:iterator>
```

UPDATE: I corrected the bit about the #, it was ok.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Using your second suggestion, nothing is showing up for output. I'm not sure why... When I do your last suggestion, each row in the table looks basically like package.entity.User@d338d3d, but each hex value after the @ is different.

Comment: Also interesting, I have an int property called "id" in my User class that does work if I put "id" where I have "username" above. None of the other String properties work, but the int property does...

Comment: Does you package.entity.User class has a sensible toString() method?
And has it a getUsername() method?

Comment: I figured it out... the username method was misspelled... Everywhere. Grr. Thanks for your help leonbloy.

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this

```
<s:iterator value="users" >
<tr>
    <td><s:property value="username" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Observe that no need of **#list** there.

The other way is

```
<s:iterator value="users" var="user">
<tr>
    <td><s:property value="#user.username" /></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

insetead of **id** give it as **var**.Since
we don’t specify a scope for var, this new ***user*** reference exists in
the default “action” scope—the ActionContext. As you can
see, we then reference it with the # operator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSTL with Struts.  It has a `<c:forEach>` tag in its core library that will allow you to iterate through a list or any other collection easily.

Answer (score 1):

```
<s:iterator value="users" var="eachUser">
<div>
 <s:property value="#eachUser.username">
</div>  
</s:iterator>
```

Check [this](http://atechiediary.blogspot.com/2013/07/struts2-how-to-display-data-contained.html) for more such examples

Answer (score -1):

Struts 1.x takes care of your inner properties like this.

< logic:iterate id="user" name="userList">
     < bean:write property="${userName}"/ >
  < /logic:iterate>

I guess as per ur example u can have. You may not need "#list." again in the value attribute
< s:iterator value="users" id="list">
                  < s:property value="userName" />
 < / s:iterator>

Comment: <s:iterate> does not have an id field.Please review