# how to iterate over a map and map values in struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

i need help here in resolving an issue. I am migrating an existing struts2 based web app to spring boot, I have managed to do that however the below piece of code is not working as expected. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<s:iterator value="{#session['user'].menu}" id = "item" status="rowStatus">
  <div class='menucontent_bg' id ='menumenucontent_<s:property value="#rowStatus.index"/>'>
    <s:iterator value="value" id = "menu"> 
      <div class=menucontent_heading>
        <a href='javascript:createTab("<s:property value ="#menu.menuOption"/>", <s:property value ="#menu.menuUrl"/>");'>

          <s:property value ="#menu.menuOption"/>
        </a>
      </div>
    </s:iterator>
  </div>
</s:iterator>
```

In the above code iteration is taking place as expected but the javascript method call to createTab is being done with empty parameters which means #menu.menuOption and other parameter passed is returning empty string, which

I am not sure why as I verified with a simple scriptlet and the values are not empty and also the same code is there in production. I upgraded struts version to 2.5.1 for migration purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find a solution. the problem was not just with iterating over a map but was with all the iteration related code in my project. So i searched with different options and finally got the answer in the link below

[How do you iterate through a list of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754939/how-do-you-iterate-through-a-list-of-objects)

with struts 2.2.x id attribute has been deprecated and replaced with var for the iterator tag. so now the working code is as below

```
               <s:iterator value="{#session['user'].menu}" var= "item" status="rowStatus">
              <div class='menucontent_bg' id 
                     ='menumenucontent_<s:property 
                           value ="#rowStatus.index"/>'>
                     <s:iterator value="value" var = "menu"> 
                     <div class=menucontent_heading>
                        <a href='javascript:createTab("<s:property         value ="#menu.menuOption"/>", <s:property value 
                                                  ="#menu.menuUrl"/>");'>

                           <s:property value ="#menu.menuOption"/>
                       </a>
                    </div>
                    </s:iterator>
              </div>
              </s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a 
  href='javascript:createTab(". <s:property value ="#menu.menuOption"/>", 
        <s:property s:property value ="#menu.menuUrl"/>");'>
```

This is (at the very least):

- Missing a quote
- Has a spurious `s:property` in the middle of the second parameter

It's almost always better, and clearer, to use intermediate values and/or functions to do work like this, e.g., move the JS into a support function, so you can read your own code.

Comment: Dave Newton, sorry for the typo however I have corrected it now, the s:property value was duplicated in one of the lines